# How to get Raspberry Pi images?

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, 21.10

The download links for the Raspberry Pi editions of Ubuntu all lead to invalid URLs. This happens both with the `rpi-imager` app and the direct download from Ubuntu's website. How I get to the 404s: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

The dead URLs: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.4/release/ubuntu-20.04.4-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz ; https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.4/release/ubuntu-20.04.4-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi.img.xz ; https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/21.10/release/ubuntu-21.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz

I'm trying to install any of the Ubuntu Server images. None of the links work. Am I missing something?

Comment: You weren't specific as to which didn't work for you, I tried two at random & they worked for me (*downloads from cdimage.ubuntu.com started as expected*),  If you jump to the bottom of the page you provided, you'll see a "*Report a bug on this site*" link, so please use it and be specific with your issue as downloads started for me.

Comment: Which two did you try? I tried https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.4/release/ubuntu-20.04.4-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz ; https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.4/release/ubuntu-20.04.4-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi.img.xz ; https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/21.10/release/ubuntu-21.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz

Comment: Must be down temporarily. Wait and try again later

Comment: We've had issues with *daily* ISO files having the .img name in recent day(s) [on cdimage.ubuntu.com]; I wonder if this is related - but sorry I have *few* details  (we've worked out a *workaround* for what we need.. you may need to do the same, but I'd still file a bug report so others aren't having issues)  --- this issue has been resolved for us anyway

Comment: Hmm. You're absolutely right. The images [are not listed as available to download](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.4/release/), but the accompanying `.manifest` files are. [This has been reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1966357), and will hopefully be resolved in short order 

Comment: Further to my prior comment ^  the bad ISO files that were named IMG have now been removed I note.. maybe they removed more than the *bad* ones in my prior comment; and these issues are related...  (as equally like they are unrelated ...  the issues I'm thinking of relate to *jammy* & *focal* only; not *impish*)

Comment: Yep.. Vorlon has linked the two..  (*fyi: it wasn't vorlon who ran the script initially if I recall correctly*) & issue will get resolved (*asap*)

Comment: @matigo  I gather the bug report is yours, I'd write up an answer using your report & details from *Steve/vorlon*s response..     The issue will be solved once restores are complete; but your bug report helped hurry the issue..  (*I can provide more details on why job was run & background issues on the why - but none apply to the OP's question*).   Thank you for your report!

Comment: @guiverc would an answer on this question not be considered off topic? This isn't an issue with Ubuntu, but with a service provided by Canonical. I'll be happy to write it up once the ticket is complete, though 

Comment: Ubuntu users are trying to download the images from a Ubuntu site, yes it's managed by Canonical staff, but the team involved includes non-Canonical staff too.. so to me *at least* it's on-topic.  Once resolved I suspect the issue to me can be closed as issue went away (*can't be reproduced & of little value to future readers*) & more off-topic than the current issue which exists currently.

Comment: @guiverc You’re right.  I flagged this as can’t be reproduced, and my flag was marked helpful, so I think you’re correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a temporary hiccup that has just recently been resolved. Based on [LaunchPad Ticket 1966357](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1966357):

> These were inadvertently removed as a result of an overly broad glob when cleaning up some daily images wrongly published with .img extension. Restoration is in progress.
> – [Steve Langasek](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1966357/comments/1)

Looking at [the release page for Ubuntu 20.04.4](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.4/release/), I can confirm that the files exist *and* that they work:

[image: Working Links]

Comment: Thanks for raising the ticket & helping getting the issue resolved quickly...